# Перекодирование в PHP из Windows 1252 в UTF-8, iconv и mb_convert_encoding не работают

Tags: ajax, php, json, utf-8

Мой скрипт получает данные GET запросом от аякс-страницы. Броузер эту страницу восприниает корректно, идентифицируя кодировку как Windows 1251. Но когда я смотрю данные в скрипте через var_dump (сам скрипт в UTF-8) получаются кракозябры типа

```
Îïåðàöèîííàÿ ñèñòåìà — Íå óñòàíîâëåíà.
```

Соответственно и в БД данные пишутся такими кракозябрами.

[Декодер](http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/advanced/) говорит:
Как нам пришлось помучиться - CP1252 → CP1251

Пробовал различные варианты перекодирования с использованием `iconv` и `mb_convert_encoding` - безрезультатно. Ясно, что проблема на поверхности, броузер же без проблем декодирует данные. Прошу помощи.

Comment: Проблему решил. Конечно красивым это решение не назовешь, но больше не хотелось тратить время на разбирательство с кодировками. Написал простейшую функцию замены символов CP1252 на соответствующие кириллические. В скрипте все ок, в БД тоже. Всем спасибо.

Comment: @Ярославский, поясните поподробнее.

Вы меняете 1 байт, соответствующий символу кириллицы в Вашей "CP1252" (в кавычках т.к. в реальной cp1252 **нет кириллических символов**) на байты UTF-8?

Про символ `№` (код 0xB9 в cp1251), который изображается 3-мя байтами в UTF-8 не забыли?

Comment: Я меняю символы типа "Îïåðàöèîííàÿ ñèñòåìà" на соответствующие им кириллические символы. В функции замены указал только символы, а не коды. Т.е. :

private function convertCP ($text) {
         $input_set = array('À','Á','Â','Ã','Ä','Å','¨','Æ','Ç','È','É','Ê','Ë',...',
              'à','á','â','ã','ä','å','¸','æ','ç','è','é','ê','...');
         $output_set = array('А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','...,
              'а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','...);
         return str_replace($input_set, $output_set, $text);

Про № спасибо, добавлю.

Comment: Тогда понятно.

  У Вас видимо винда, и файл с  `text` видимо в  кодировке UTF-16 и в нем **действительно** коды символов Latin-1 (0x80 - 0xff). Поэтому PHP и не мог ничего перекодировать.

  А вот почему редактор (или чем этот файл создавали) решил, что исходные данные (однобайтные) это Latin-1 (cp1252), а не кириллица (cp1251) это вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Ничо не понял, но попробую:

```
iconv("CP1252", "CP1251", $text);
```

Comment: Это я пробовал сразу. Результат
 Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in...

Если так:
    iconv("CP1252", "CP1251//IGNORE", $text);
Результат - кракозябры другого типа. Пробовал преобразовывать сначала в 1251, потом это уже в UTF-8 - безрезультатно. iconv пишет либо нотисы, либо кракозябры. mb_convert.. - кракозябры.

Comment: @Ярославский ок. В какой кодировке страница, с которой отправляется GET запрос? Запрос точно ajax'ом отправляется? Т.к. эти запросы в UTF-8 кодировке отправляются.

Comment: Не совсем верно объяснил сразу. Мой скрипт на PHP отправляет запрос используя file_get_contents() к этой странице

http://www.oldi.ru/catalog/catalog_section_ajax.php?CU_PAGE=100000&SID=6921&SHOW_ALL=Y&SHOW_TYPE=1

Страница - обработчик аякс запросов, очевидно.
Мой скрипт в кодировке UTF-8

Данные, не считая кодировки, скрипт от этой страницы получает верные. Проблема только в кодировке.

Comment: Попробуйте [задать внутреннюю кодировку скрипта](http://php.ru/manual/function.mb-internal-encoding.html) и на всякий пожарный - вы сохраняли документ, как UTF-8 без BOM?

Comment: @Ярославский, а просто
 
    

    iconv("CP1251", "UTF-8", $text);

не пробовали?

IMHO текст у Вас изначально в cp1251, вот и преобразуйте его в кодировку скрипта.

Comment: Deonis, я проверил исходную кодировку (та же самая функция без параметров) - ISO-8859-1, поменял на UTF-8 - никакого результата
Сохранял я PHPExpertEditor там две опции ANSI и UTF-8, но IMHO не тут собака. Там проблема в двойной перекодировке. Т.е. мне надо ISO-8859-1 (СP1252) преобразовать сначала в CP1251, так как изначально там как раз CP1251 страница дает, а потом в UTF-8, так как скрипт должен быть в этой кодировке, но почему-то не хотят стандартные функции даже в CP1251 преобразовывать. Броузеры это делают без проблем. Где-то проблема втом как это делает PHP.
.
avp, пробовал - кракозябр

Comment: > Где-то проблема втом как это делает PHP

@Ярославский, Ну, вы же не уникальны? )) Если у вас все страницы в кодировке utf-8 без BOM, то проблем просто не должно возникать. Поверьте на слово, у меня пять проектов, которые работают полностью без перезагрузок (jQuery + ajax + php) и ни разу не возникло проблем. А вот самый первый сайт, в котором я применял эти технологии, заставил помучаться, т.к. по неопытности, я страницу, с которой отправлялся запрос, сделал в cp1251, а handler - utf-8. Не на все 100, но практически уверен, что проблема в не правильной кодировке документов.

Comment: @Ярославский, ISO-8859-1 (СP1252) преобразовать в CP1251 **принципиально невозможно**, т.к. обе кодировки однобайтные. 

Т.е. UCS полученные из кодов символов СP1252 не соответствуют кодам CP1251 и наоборот.

Вам надо разобраться, почему PHP "считает", что `text` в кодировке СP1252, а не CP1251.

Comment: P.S. @Ярославский, ради интереса - уберите всё "секретное" из ваших скриптов и выложите где-нибудь на файлообменник.

Comment: И как всегда в ответ автор напишет, что не заметил одной детали - всем спасибо. :D Скачайте Notepad++ и преобразуйте в Utf-8 без BOM. Utf-8 и Utf-8 без BOM не одно и тоже. Не будет у Вас проблем!

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы, завтра воспользуюсь вашими советами, о результате отпишусь.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой. Загвоздка оказалась в том, что для обмена данными между PHP-скриптом и базой данных MySQL не была задана кодировка по-умолчанию. После задания все заработало как надо:

```
// изменение набора символов на utf8 
if (!$conn->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Ошибка при загрузке набора символов utf8: %s\n", $conn->error());
} else {
    printf("Текущий набор символов: %s\n", $conn->character_set_name());
}
```